# Floating widget restarting issue in Android pre - API 26 (> API 26)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I have an application where I have a floating widget running as Service.

But whenever I close the app, the widget (service) is restarted. this doesn't happen on API 26+

**manifest.xml**

```
 <service
        android:name=".widget"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

**widget.java**

```
public class widget extends Service {

private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private View view;
static boolean expanded = false;



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.widget, null);


    int layoutFlag = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : TYPE_PHONE;
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            layoutFlag,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.START;


    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    mWindowManager.addView(view, params);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (view != null) {
        mWindowManager.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, widget.class);
startService(intent);
```

**Note: Permission is granted**

So this works fine on any device above or equal to API 26
and it still works on devices below api 26 but it has that restarting issue, any idea what might be causing that and how can I deal with it?

also notice the only thing that differs the 2 versions in code is this part

```
int layoutFlag = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : TYPE_PHONE;
```

Comment: Where you added the `MainActivity` source code? I meant position in `MainActivity`

Comment: in OnCreate method, I check first if it's already running, if not I start it.